# How to pass selected value from DropDownList to action method of controller though viewmodel?

Tags: kendo-ui, dropdown

Below is the sample code. When I use DropDownListFor, I am getting error.
Even ComboBoxFor is not working.

InvalidOperationException: You cannot override component name when bound to a model expression.

```
                 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model=>model.CategoryID)
                .Name("CategoryID")
                .DataTextField("Value")
                .DataValueField("CategoryID")
                .DataSource(source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action("GetCategoryData", "Quote");
                    });
                })
                .Enable(false)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" }))
```

Comment: Simply remove line `.Name("CategoryID")`, id and name attributes will be generated automatically from passed expression.

Comment: I have removed .Name("CategoryID"). Now it is not showing any error. But value is not pass through viewmodel to controller when form is submitted.

Comment: Do you have something selected in the dropdown? Which model do you use in your controller action method? Have you tried to inspect the form data which is sent to the server on submit?

Comment: Thanks for help. Data is pass to controller now.

Comment: In my code the requirement is  disable the drop down and set default  value for some of the permission. Because of these two properties value is not passing to controller.

Comment: @Sonali, how did you pass the value to controller without the .Name property?